# enable cipher suites with sha256/sha384 on Android 4

Tags: android, ssl, https

How can you use ciphers with sha256/384 like TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 on Android 4 ?

On my Android 4.4.2 tablet SSLSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites only lists the SHA ciphers without numbers.  The SSLSocket documentation even says it is only supported from [Android 5](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) on.

However, when I open a website in the browser (com.android.browser) on my   Android 4.4.2 tablet, it includes TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in the handshake and opens  sites from servers that only supports these ciphers successfully. So somehow it is possible

Comment: My guess is that browser includes its own implementation of those cipher suites.

Comment: perhaps there is some library i can use for that?

Comment: Hi @BeniBela, have you found any clue about this question?